# Как получить id авторизовавшегося пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, есть рабочая авторизация пользователя на php для swift приложения. Нужно получить и передать id пользователя, подскажите как дополнить этот код

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
if($_POST) {
$username   = $_POST['username'];
$password   = $_POST['password'];

if($username && $password) {

        $db_name     = 'mysite';
        $db_user     = 'root';
        $db_password = '12345';
        $server_url  = 'localhost';

        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

        /* check connection */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            error_log("Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"' . mysqli_connect_error() . '"}';
        } else {
            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT login FROM users WHERE login = ? and password = ?")) {

                //$password = $password;
               // $id = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE login=?";
                /* bind parameters for markers */
                $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);

                /* execute query */
                $stmt->execute();

                /* bind result variables */
                $stmt->bind_result($id1);

                /* fetch value */
                $stmt->fetch();

                /* close statement */
                $stmt->close();

            }

            /* close connection */
            $mysqli->close();

            if ($id1) {
                error_log("User $username: password match.");
                echo '{"success":1}';
            } else {
                error_log("User $username: password doesn't match.");
                echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Invalid Username/Password"}';
            }
        }
} else {
    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Invalid Username/Password."}';
}
}else {
echo '{"succ11ess":0,"error_message":"Invalid Data."}';
}
?>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А где структура таблицы?

Comment: да и на будущее в php есть функция `json_encode()`

Comment: Ну как структура, таблица users в ней id, login и password

Comment: мне именно в этом коде надо как то передать id, для того чтобы потом в приложении его использовать. Можно как-нибудь запихнуть его в bind_param, или как то по другому передать?

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас в базе id пользователя хранится в колонке id, то поменяйте слегка запрос:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = ? and password = ?
```

Тогда в вашей переменной $id1 у вас будет id пользователя.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Разобрался